# How to use OSLEC with Alsa as default, not with Pulseaudio or other thirdparty package involved?

Tags: configuration, audio, alsa, pulseaudio, echo

[Oslec Echo canceller](http://www.rowetel.com/blog/?page_id=454)

I have seen some packages used OSLEC and there echo cancle was very well. So for a test simulation, how could i install the OSLEC only with Alsa (i do not use PulseAudio at all, cause it has many broken packages cause unstable).

How can you install OSLEC and Alsa configuration on Ubuntu 12.04 64/bit kernel 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Echo cancel:

1) Automatic: 
- read peak/rms/decay: to find the high and low audio wave
- based on the audio/voice detection, use the microphone level and speaker level to low volume, its a algorithm to make it work

- sound card has to have mic and speaker on same card, well it can be separated too if you make the algorithm yourself

2) Manually 
- use mic on / speaker off, speaker on/ mic off to make (half duplex echo cancel)